# In the given sentence, is the article ''an'' needed or not?

Tags: articles, syntactic-analysis

> A computer is both a useful and an essential device.

Comment: You do not need it, no. You could remove a lot of those words, and should remove *useful*, as everything essential is useful. People know that a computer is a device too. You could just write... *Computers are essential.* Also, this question would be a much better fit for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @CarlSmith I find myself in disagreement with your rhetoric here. Whilst anything which is *essential* is *useful*, its *essentiality* does not necessarily exhaust all the attributes of its *usefulness*. In other words my computer may be useful for doing A,B, and C. But only A is *essential*. Therefore my machine's *usefulness* extends beyond its *essential* functions. Hence there is nothing illogical about saying *A computer is both a useful and an essential device*. And that is exactly how I would say it.

Comment: Calling my comment rhetoric is a bit unfair. I was just saying that nothing can be essential and useless, and that it's generally a bad idea to use ten words, when three would do the same job.

Comment: If he wants to emphasize a particular reason for it being essential, there's no reason not to include it.

Comment: @CarlSmith There is nothing unfair about describing someone's comment as [rhetoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetoric). Indeed it should be taken as a complement. *Rhetoric* is the honourable art of discourse, and an immense field of study dating back at least as far as the Greeks. The difference between your argument and mine falls in the scope of rhetoric to supply an answer. If something is useful for A,B and C where only A is essential, is the thing both useful and essential or simply essential. It is on those sorts of things that Socrates and Plato opined.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should actually *omit* the article *an*, since *and* joins the modifiers *useful* and *essential*, which both directly modify *a device*:

> a (useful and essential) device

If this were a list of items, each with its own distinct modifier, I think the proper way to list them is either all with- or all without the respective article.

Answer (score 0):

Your original sentence already presents readers with a shortened version of this longer idea:

> A computer is a useful device and it is an essential device.

In shortening it, you adopted the tactic of putting two phrases into parallel, which you signaled by adding the word *both* before the start of the branches:

> A computer is both
>
> - a useful [device]
>
> and
>
> - an essential device.

Then you dropped the first occurrence of *device* so that the two parallel branches re-merge at *device* at the end of the sentence. Now you want to know whether you can drop *an* before *essential* and keep the rest of the sentence the same.

My answer is that you can remove *an* from your original sentence, but you can't do so without damaging the sentence's parallelism unless you make additional alterations to rebalance the sentence. One option is to get rid of the parallel construction signaled by *both* and run the two adjectives in series rather than in parallel:

> A computer is a useful and essential device.

Another option is to retain the parallel structure while removing the articles (*a* and *an*) and *device*:

> A computer is both useful and essential.

If you like, you can retain the parallelism while dropping *both* from the sentence:

> A computer is useful and essential.

But if you keep *both* and the *a* before useful, *both* acts as the node that "a useful" and "an essential" attach to; consequently, for consistent parallelism, you have to retain the *an* before *essential*, too:

> A computer is both a useful and an essential device.